# GA4 events sent via Measurement Protocol 2 do not inherit session parameters

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm sending events to GA4 using measurement protocol 2 (such events as begin_checkout, purchase, refund). I can see these events in reports, in user explorer, with correct timestamps, but all these events do not inherit session parameters. All events has desktop device type and (not set) in country, city, device model etc

Here example of payload:

```
{"client_id":"123.123",
"user_id":"123123",
"timestamp_micros":"1686902248544958",
"events": [{
    "name":"begin_checkout",
    "params":
        {"currency":"EUR",
        "value":100.0,
        "transaction_id":"123123",
        "items":[{
            "item_id":"123123",
            "item_name":"T-Shirt",
            "price":1000.0,
            "discount":0.0,
            "affiliation":123123,
            "item_category":"Clothes",
            "item_category2":"Shirts",
            "quantity":2
            }],
        "session_id":"123123123" }}]}
```

It seems that the event is not connected with the session, but I pass session_id on request.
All my events are correct (according to ga-dev-tools).
I don't understand how I can fix that. It looks like a bug in GA4.
I will be glad to any advice.